# Removing certain characters from a long string in python

Tags: python, string

I'm working on a project that involves taking some source code and boiling it down to just the words that are displayed on the page. I can get it to remove all the html tags, and all of the stuff between script tags, but I can't figure out how to remove all the characters that start with a backslash. A page will have \t, \n, and \x** where * seem to be any lowercase letter or number.

How would I write a code that would replace all these parts of the strings with spaces? I'm working in python.

For example, this is a string from a webpage:

```
\n\t\n\t\n\t\tApple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tLanguage:English\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9Aragon\xc3\xa9sAsturianuAz\xc9\x99rbaycanca\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\x82\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbeB\xc3\xa2n-l\xc3\xa2m-g\xc3\xbaBasa Banyumasan\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0
```

would become:

```
Apple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Language:English sAsturianuAz rbaycanca Basa Banyumasan
```

Comment: Post a short example with desired output

Comment: If it's Wikipedia content in particular that you are interested in, it's better to use the database dumps that Wikipedia provides: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Comment: Your output is a little bit ambiguous. For example where is `Aragon` and `B`, `n`, `l`, `m`, and `g` in your output. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = repr('''\n\t\n\t\n\t\tApple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tLanguage:English\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9Aragon\xc3\xa9sAsturianuAz\xc9\x99rbaycanca\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\x82\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbeB\xc3\xa2n-l\xc3\xa2m-g\xc3\xbaBasa Banyumasan\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0''')
s =  re.sub(r'\\[tn]', '', s)
s =  re.sub(r'\\x..', '', s)
print s
```

Comment: Why would you want to know the number of substitutions in this case? That's the only difference between sub and subn

Comment: This one looks close, but when I type it the string doesn't close after the r'\\[tn]', and the r also goes the color of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to match all the desired patters and then replace them with a space.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the plain text words contains at least three chars:

```
' '.join(re.findall(r'\w{3,}', s)) # where s represents the string
```

Or:

```
' '.join(re.findall(r'(?:\w{3,}|-(?=\s))', s)) # in order to preserve the dash char
```

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia uses UTF-8 string encoding. To convert to plain ASCII, you must

1. convert from UTF-8 to unicode
2. convert from unicode to ASCII, with replacement of uncodable characters
3. convert the uncodable-character-replacements to spaces
4. convert multiple whitespaces (tabs, linefeeds, etc) to single spaces
5. strip leading and trailing spaces

.

```
s = "\n\t\n\t\n\t\tApple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\tLanguage:English\xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8\xb9\xd8\xb1\xd8\xa8\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9Aragon\xc3\xa9sAsturianuAz\xc9\x99rbaycanca\xe0\xa6\xac\xe0\xa6\xbe\xe0\xa6\x82\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xbeB\xc3\xa2n-l\xc3\xa2m-g\xc3\xbaBasa Banyumasan\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd0\xba"

import re
whitespaces = re.compile('\s+', flags=re.M)
def utf8_to_ascii(s, ws=whitespaces):
    s = s.encode("utf8")
    s = s.decode("ascii", errors="replace")
    s = s.replace(u"\ufffd", " ")
    s = ws.sub(" ", s)
    return s.strip()

s = utf8_to_ascii(s)
```

which finally results in the string

```
Apple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Language:English Aragon sAsturianuAz rbaycanca B n-l m-g Basa Banyumasan
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming default ascii encoding, we can do this quite nicely in one line, **without evil regex ;)**, by iterating over the string and removing values based on their encoding value using `ord(i) < 128`, or whatever specification we choose:

```
>>> ' '.join(''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in mystring]).split())
#Output:
Apple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Language:English Aragon sAsturianuAz rbaycanca B n-l m-g Basa Banyumasan
```

Or we could specify a string of allowed characters and use 'in', like this using the builtin 
 `string.ascii_letters`:

```
>>> import string
>>> ' '.join(''.join([i if i in string.ascii_letters else ' ' for i in mystring]).split())
#Output:
Apple Wikipedia the free encyclopedia Language English Aragon sAsturianuAz rbaycanca B n l m g Basa Banyumasan
```

This removes punctuation too (but we could easily avoid that by adding those characters back into a string check definition if we want, `check = string.ascii_letters + ',.-:'`)